# How do I convert to browser timezones using phstc dateFormat?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

**EDIT :** Btw, I have no idea why this question was marked as a duplicate. **The answers in the original question does not work for me.** i.e, getting wrong results and stuffs. Furthermore, none of the answers **deal with phstc's dateFormat function**. Do correct me if I'm wrong. Btw, I have solved this question. Do take a look at my answer.

I want to **change a UTC datetime to my browser's timezone**. I'm using [phstc's dateFormat](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat) in pure javascript form. Let's say I convert a datetime of `2014-06-27 07:11:16` using a javascript Date() function. The result I got was

```
Fri Jun 27 2014 07:11:16 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)
```

Then when I use phstc's toBrowserTimeZone function, it still returns me the same datetime. I wanted to get something like `2014-06-27 15:11:16`

Here is the code below:

```
var originalDateTime = new Date(`2014-06-27 07:11:16`);
alert(DateFormat.format.toBrowserTimeZone(originalDateTime,"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this statement in phstc's dateFormat page,

```
value = String representing date in ISO time (“2013-09-14T23:22:33Z”) or String representing 
default JAXB formatting of java.util.Date (“2013-09-14T16:22:33.527-07:00”) or String representing 
Unix Timestamp (Sat Sep 14 2013 16:22:33 GMT-0700 (PDT)) or javascript date object.
```

JS Date object should work but unfortunately, it didn't. Well, I got it fixed by changing the datetime to other formats stated above first before calling the toBrowserTimeZone() function. For example,

```
 var originalDateTime = DateFormat.format.date('2014-06-27 07:11:16',"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
 var newDateTime = DateFormat.format.toBrowserTimeZone(originalDateTime);
```